# Trying to create short link in Twilio SMS

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api

I have an outbound application that sends SMS to customers.

In each SMS is a link to a web-page that they click on.

Each link is unique to each customer so that I can identify who they are.

I know there are short link tools around but I need to have a unique link for each customer.

Does Twilio have a nice solution for this?  Or do I need to insert a long URL in each SMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio doesn't have an in built URL shortener for plain SMS (though this is an option [when sending MMS messages](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181228-Why-do-my-messages-include-a-Twilio-URL-)).

I recommend using a URL shortening API, like the [Bitly API](https://dev.bitly.com/). You can make a request to shorten your URL, then use the result when [sending the SMS with the Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages).

Comment: Hi @philnash - thanks for the reply, although a bit off topic do you know if we can get a base Bitly URL and then just add a parameter to make it unique to each message.  Just don't want to be generate a Bitly URL for every SMS.

Comment: You can't do that with Bitly (or any URL shortening APIs that I can think of), but I guess you could build your own little service that did that with a short url of your own. The Bitly API is robust and has been around for a long while, so can likely deal with your application's demands.

Comment: you've been a great help, reckon I'll build my own short url.

Comment: would love to url-shortening as an add-on feature (happy to pay for it) because getting additional 3rd party APIs approved for use by some systems is next to impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has had this feature since 2022:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/how-to-configure-link-shortening